# leiningen new throws exception

Tags: clojure, ubuntu-14.04, leiningen

I did have a functionnal leiningen installation but it seems I can't create new projects anymore. Anything using `lein new X` fails.

Example :

```
lein new app my-stuff
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.flatland.drip.Main.invoke(Main.java:117)
    at org.flatland.drip.Main.start(Main.java:88)
    at org.flatland.drip.Main.main(Main.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2093)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at stencil.core$loading__4958__auto__.invoke(core.clj:1)
    at stencil.core__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at stencil.core__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2093)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
    at leiningen.new.templates$loading__4958__auto__.invoke(templates.clj:11)
    at leiningen.new.templates__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at leiningen.new.templates__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2093)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
    at leiningen.new$loading__4958__auto__.invoke(new.clj:1)
    at leiningen.new__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at leiningen.new__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2093)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:430)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at leiningen.core.utils$require_resolve.invoke(utils.clj:80)
    at leiningen.core.utils$require_resolve.invoke(utils.clj:83)
    at leiningen.core.main$lookup_task_var.invoke(main.clj:68)
    at leiningen.core.main$pass_through_help_QMARK_.invoke(main.clj:78)
    at leiningen.core.main$task_args.invoke(main.clj:81)
    at leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke(main.clj:318)
    at leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__6160.invoke(main.clj:392)
    at leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke(main.clj:385)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:388)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:160)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
    at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:315)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:420)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:482)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:401)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:171)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:700)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/data/priority_map__init.class or clojure/data/priority_map.clj on classpath: , compiling:(clojure/core/cache.clj:1:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7142)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at stencil.loader$fn__11439.invoke(loader.clj:43)
    at stencil.loader__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at stencil.loader__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/data/priority_map__init.class or clojure/data/priority_map.clj on classpath: 
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:443)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5066.invoke(core.clj:5641)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5640)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5446)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5015.invoke(core.clj:5486)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5485)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5524)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:626)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5607)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core.cache$eval6153$loading__4958__auto____6154.invoke(cache.clj:9)
    at clojure.core.cache$eval6153.invoke(cache.clj:9)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6703)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6692)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7130)
    ... 128 more
```

I can still use `lein repl` and others though.
My system :

```
$ lein -v
Leiningen 2.5.1 on Java 1.8.0_40 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM


$ file `which java javac`
/usr/bin/java:  symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/java' 
/usr/bin/javac: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/javac' 

file /etc/alternatives/java /etc/alternatives/javac
/etc/alternatives/java:  symbolic link to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java' 
/etc/alternatives/javac: symbolic link to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac'
```

I tried a `lein upgrade`, but I get a "Leiningen is already up-to-date.".
How do I fix my setup to be able to create new projects ?

EDIT :
Here is my `~/.lein/profiles.clj` :

```
$ cat profiles.clj 

; https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/Plugins
{ :user { :plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.8.2"]         ; cider-jack-in
                    [lein-cljsbuild "1.0.4"]            ;; 1.0.4 is a requirement
                    [lein-figwheel "0.2.5"]             ; browser reload
                    ;[lein-drip "0.1.1-SNAPSHOT"]        ; faster JVM loading
                    [lein-midje "3.1.3"]                ; tests
                    [lein-exec "0.3.4"]                 ; execute a single .clj file
                    [lein-ancient "0.6.5"]              ; detect outdated dependencies
                    [lein-typed "0.3.5"]                ; core.typed plugin
                    [lein-kibit "0.0.8"]               
                    [lein-vanity "0.2.0"]
                    [lein-hiera "0.9.0"]                ; image of deps
                    [lein-bikeshed "0.2.0"]
                    [venantius/ultra "0.1.9"]]
         :ultra {:color-scheme :solarized_dark}}}
```

Comment: is this since your update to java 1.8.0_40?

Comment: @cfrick Well I can't remember to be honest. It's been quite some time... But I think that I started with java 8 straight away when learning Clojure.

Comment: @cfrick There is a message involving drip (a plugin that I use) in the stacktrace. But I don't know how to disable it, maybe this is linked ?

Comment: check your `~/.lein/profiles.clj` for plugins; yet that file not found stuff does not look good either.  this is no system wide installation of lein, just for your user, right?

Comment: @cfrick just posted my profiles. `$ which lein
/home/nha/bin/lein`, so I guess just for my user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hey dude just exclude core.cache dependency in your ~/.lein/profiles.clj it will work

```
[lein-figwheel "0.2.5" :exclusions [org.clojure/core.cache]]
```

there are some reason which are discussed on following github issue.

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1563

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1739